# Why does LongSummaryStatistics implement IntConsumer?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Why does `LongSummaryStatistics` implement `IntConsumer` when there is `IntSummaryStatistics` which also implements `IntConsumer`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`LongSummaryStatistics` implements `IntConsumer` in order that it can accept `int` values as well as `long` values.

For example, this allows you to pass it to a method requiring an `IntConsumer` in order to consume some `int` data abstractly:

```
LongSummaryStatistics lss = new LongSummaryStatistics();
someMethod(lss);

void someMethod(IntConsumer consumer) { ... }
```

There's no real reason why a `LongSummaryStatistics` shouldn't be usable for this purpose: `int` can always be widened to `long` without loss. However, the type system wouldn't allow `lss` to be used as a parameter to `someMethod` unless `LongSummaryStatistics` implemented `IntConsumer` directly.

True, you could do this without implementing the interface, using a lambda:

```
someMethod(i -> lss.consume(i));
```

but it's just a bit neater to use the reference directly.

Comment: @nullpointer try defining a class which doesn't implement `IntConsumer`, and then pass it to a method which requires an `IntConsumer` parameter.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "why let consumers define separate streams of int and long and then mix them"? Streams are not the only sources of data for `*SummaryStatistics`, you can invoke the methods directly.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for sharing this view. I have never thought along this perspective. I always wonder why implement IntConsumer accept(int i) when accept(long i) can take in int as well